# bgStretcher (jQuery) in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I came across the following code online:

http://www.ajaxblender.com/bgstretcher-2-jquery-stretch-background-plugin-updated.html

It works like a charm on HTML & Javascript & CSS.

Now the question is how do I implement this kind of code in Ruby on Rails Environment.

I have split off this question in multiple questions:

- where do I place the CSS & jQuery
- how do I implement the javascript into the erb file
- how do I link to my css & jQuery files (like in HTML)

Kind regards,
Vincent

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to go through asset pipleline which will clear up a lot of things

[http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html](http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline)

http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline